# Color codes for discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I found it a bit difficult and annoying to change colors in discord.py (embed color for instance). I made a class for the different color codes to use in discord.py which can be imported into the main file.

```py
class colors:
    default = 0
    teal = 0x1abc9c
    dark_teal = 0x11806a
    green = 0x2ecc71
    dark_green = 0x1f8b4c
    blue = 0x3498db
    dark_blue = 0x206694
    purple = 0x9b59b6
    dark_purple = 0x71368a
    magenta = 0xe91e63
    dark_magenta = 0xad1457
    gold = 0xf1c40f
    dark_gold = 0xc27c0e
    orange = 0xe67e22
    dark_orange = 0xa84300
    red = 0xe74c3c
    dark_red = 0x992d22
    lighter_grey = 0x95a5a6
    dark_grey = 0x607d8b
    light_grey = 0x979c9f
    darker_grey = 0x546e7a
    blurple = 0x7289da
    greyple = 0x99aab5
```

It is possible to use e.g. `colors.red` if red color is wanted. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You could also use RGB codes by doing

```
embed=discord.Embed(COLOR=discord.Color.from_rgb(RGB code)
```

Answer (score 4):

You already have the **[`discord.Colour`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=colour#discord.Colour)** class (or `discord.Color`) for this:

```py
from discord import Color

teal = Color.teal()
```

You can even change `Color` to everything you want like so:

```py
from discord import Color as c

teal = c.teal()
```

You can look at **[discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)** for more informations.

Comment: thanks, thats were i found the color codes from but  the reason i made my own class was because the discord.colour wasnt working for me

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make custom colors you can do that as well. It would be as simple as getting them from RGB or HEX Color codes. Getting them from RGB would be:

```
import discord
beige = discord.Color.from_rgb(225, 198, 153)
```

and then for HEX color codes, it would be even simpler (not even needing to import discord) and just:

```
dark_red = 0x992d22
```

as you have above. Although you may want to not spend the time searching up the RGB/HEX color codes so discord has a built-in color system. The way you'd use that is by:

```
import discord
blue = discord.Color.blue()
```

read more about the color documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=color#colour):

Answer (score 1):

Discord already give a Color library for it

```py
emeb= discord.Embed(title = "title", description = "description", color = Color.red())
```

Or try "Color." And then press Ctrl+space for auto complete and it gives you all the available Colors and RGB RGBA formats

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with

`discord.Color.Red()`

if you want colors from RGB format you can use

`discord.Color.from_rgb(000,000,000)`

Answer (score 1):

You can check colors in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/search.html?q=color)! Or here is a quick example for colors:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="Embed's title", description="Description", color=discord.Color.blue())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessary. You do not need to implement your own colour codes as discord.py already does that for you.
The [`discord.Color`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Color) class has many built-in colour codes for you to use.
The `discord.Color` class also provides great methods for you to use such as:
`from_hsv`, `from_rgb`, `from_str`, and `to_rgb` which allow great customisation for your colors.

docs:
[`discord.Color`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Color)
[`discord`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31946915)