# How to create color role with discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command that creates a role with its color by typing it in the message however i kepp getting this error

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: role() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'color'

```
    @commands.command(aliases=['make_role'])
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
    async def role(self, ctx, *, name,color):
        guild=ctx.guild
        await guild.create_role(name=name, color=colors)
        await ctx.send(f'Role `{name}` has been created, color is {colors}')
```

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk `*` in your function parameters is causing the issue you are experiencing.
The asterisk tells the function that the following parameters should be regarded as a certain number of variables put into a single argument. So it assumes that everything you type with `!role Gordon Freeman Blue` is regarded as the name parameter. So when you `print(name)` it will output `Gordon Freeman Blue`.

A simple fix would to move the parameter positions around as colours are normally just one word.

```
async def role(self, ctx, color, *, name):
```

Btw, this line will cause an error as you've put an extra `s` on the `color=colors`

```
await guild.create_role(name=name, color=colors)
```

Comment: after doing that it showed this error
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'
caused by this line:
        await guild.create_role(name=name, color=colors)

Comment: The colour needs to be a discord.Colour object. I don't think you can just say "Blue"? You can also use hex codes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63768372/color-codes-for-discord-py

Comment: I know, i tried hex codes and color objects and both of them didnt work

Comment: Could you post the code of your attempts? Maybe it's the name variable, try switching it to a test string

Comment: This is my code: 
https://imgur.com/a/zZE5ng4

This is the error i keep getting:
https://imgur.com/a/07DfBx2

Comment: You aren't passing a colour. You can't just write "discord.Colour("Blue")" into your discord command. It'll be passed as a string. You need to make a way of converting the string ("Blue") into an *object* of discord.Colour("Blue"). Or if you're using HexCode, String -> Hex.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @KELO's Answer but the error is when we use **#** when adding a color It will never work because discord.py get it as a channel. So you should get that required arguments from DMS

Answer (score -1):

a couple of things:

1. you have no variable whose name of it is colors.
2. color is a class
   "colour (Union[Colour, int]) – The colour for the role. Defaults to Colour.default(). This is aliased to color as well."
   as an example, you can see this
   `discord.Colour(0xa45141)` to create a color